# joining a table to another table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to grab the data from, https://www.espn.com/nhl/standings

When I try to grab it, it is putting Florida Panthers one row to high and messing up the data. All the team names need to be shifted down a row. I have tried to mutate the data and tried,

```
dataset_one = dataset_one.shift(1)
```

and then joining with the stats table but I am getting NaN.

The docs seem to show a lot of ways of joining and merging data with similar columns headers but not sure the best solution here without a similar column header to join with.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

page = pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/nhl/standings')

dataset_one = page[0]   # Team Names
dataset_two = page[1]   # Stats

combined_data = dataset_one.join(dataset_two)
print(combined_data)
```

Output:

```
 FLAFlorida Panthers  GP  W  L  OTL  ...  GF  GA  DIFF    L10 STRK
0  CBJColumbus Blue Jackets   6  5  0    1  ...  22  16     6  5-0-1   W2
1    CARCarolina Hurricanes  10  4  3    3  ...  24  28    -4  4-3-3   L1
2           DALDallas Stars   6  5  1    0  ...  18  10     8  5-1-0   W4
3     TBTampa Bay Lightning   6  4  1    1  ...  23  14     9  4-1-1   L2
4     CHIChicago Blackhawks   6  4  1    1  ...  19  14     5  4-1-1   W1
5    NSHNashville Predators  10  3  4    3  ...  26  31    -5  3-4-3   W1
6      DETDetroit Red Wings   8  4  4    0  ...  20  24    -4  4-4-0   L1
```

Desired:

```
                             GP  W  L  OTL  ...  GF  GA  DIFF    L10 STRK
    0    FLAFlorida Panthers   6  5  0    1  ...  22  16     6  5-0-1   W2
    1    CBJColumbus Blue Jackets  10  4  3    3  ...  24  28    -4  4-3-3   L1
    2    CARCarolina Hurricanes         6  5  1    0  ...  18  10     8  5-1-0   W4
    3    DALDallas Stars    6  4  1    1  ...  23  14     9  4-1-1   L2
    4    TBTampa Bay Lightning  6  4  1    1  ...  19  14     5  4-1-1   W1
    5    CHIChicago Blackhawks  10  3  4    3  ...  26  31    -5  3-4-3   W1
    6    NSHNashville Predators  8  4  4    0  ...  20  24    -4  4-4-0   L1
    7    DETDetriot Red Wings 10  2  6  2   6   ...  20  35   -15  2-6-2   L6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an alternative approach to @Noah's answer. You can first add an extra row, `shift` the df down by a row and then assign the header col as index 0 value.

```
import pandas as pd

page = pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/nhl/standings')
dataset_one = page[0]  # Team Names
dataset_two = page[1]  # Stats

# Shifting down by one row
dataset_one.loc[max(dataset_one.index) + 1, :] = None
dataset_one = dataset_one.shift(1)
dataset_one.iloc[0] = dataset_one.columns
dataset_one.columns = ['team']

combined_data = dataset_one.join(dataset_two)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. This seems to be working for me. Just to clarify cause I'm fairly new to Pandas but you are shifting the table down one row and then setting the location to the first position and adding the column title of "Team"? Then joining them? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm actually now seeing an issue with this solution as its overlapping the second column and cutting off the Columbus Blue Jackets

Comment: `shift` isn't inplace

Comment: Yes, exactly. Shift every row down by one; fill the now empty first row with data from header; rename the header; continue with the processing.

Comment: @DOBS - I saw that too. Let me update the solution.

Comment: If you have the time awesome if not no problem, I'm going to keep messing around with it. Sometimes I think the best solution may be to just move onto a different place to get your data lol

Comment: @DOBS - I updated the solution. It should work now. shift was indeed losing the last row. So first an empty row should be created at bottom before shifting down.

Comment: Thank you @AnkurSaxena !!! And everyone else for the ideas and help!

Answer (score 0):

Just create the df slightly differently so it knows what is the proper header

```
dataset_one = pd.DataFrame(page[0], columns=["Team Name"])
```

Then when you `join` it should be aligned properly.

Another alternative is to do the following:

```
dataset_one = page[0].to_frame(name='Team Name')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to leave this answer. However when I do this I am getting NaN for all the team names under the column. Not sure the reason behind this or if I'm implementing your code wrong but that's what I'm getting.

Comment: are you getting NaN before or after the join?

Comment: Both before and after. I am getting NaN under every item under the "Team Name" column and the other alternative method I'm getting, "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'". Not sure what it could be